# How can I make my code check for more RGB values and how to add confidence to it?

Tags: python, pyautogui

How can I make this check for more than one rgb value (not only 0, also 1 and 2) and how can I add confidence to it? (if it's possible)

```
if pyautogui.pixel(1100, 300)[0] == 0:
```

It's probably a stupid question but I want to be sure I'm doing it correctly

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "add confidence"?

Comment: oh my bad, you probably can't add confidence to a single pixel, you can probably make the pixel color range from for example 15 to 20, right?

Comment: I had never used pyautogui. From the docs, you can use `pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(100, 200, (130, 135, 144))` to match a specific value, and `pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(100, 200, (140, 125, 134), tolerance=10)` to match ranges (the same range for R, G and B)